# При запуске .exe созданного PyInstaller выдаёт ошибку pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, aiogram, pyinstaller

Пытаюсь конвертировать свой python-файл c использованием библиотеки aiogram в .exe:
`pyinstaller --paths venv/Lib/site-packages -F starter.py`

При запуске .exe файла выдаёт ошибку

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'magic_filter' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Comment: Что Вы импортируете в исходных файлах?

Comment: Импортирую aiogram и ещё несколько библиотек. Если убрать aiogram, то всё работает.

Comment: Вы запускаете из-под виртуального оружения, зачем тогда --paths? pyinstaller тоже должен быть установлен в виртуалку. Когда запускаете pyinstaller - он формирует *.spec - там всё, что он использует, когда делает бинарник. aiogram - тоже установлен под виртуалкой. Запускаете виртуалку и под ней всё делаете

Comment: @Виктор а если я компилирую вот так `pyinstaller bot.py --onefile` , и у меня та же ошибка при открытие .exe, то что мне делать?

Comment: @Виктор --paths это уже была попытка исправить ошибку. Она, похоже, возникает из-за упаковки в один файл.

Comment: Нужно --hidden-import magic_filter   - как-то так

Comment: @Виктор пробовал. Не помогает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При создании `.exe (pyinstaller)` допишите в параметры:

```
--copy-metadata magic_filter
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)